# Is this the wrong way to go about updating a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this code to try to update the q_id column of table a with the q_id values of table b. I feel as if this is inefficient and the wrong way to go about it because it's taking a very long time to run. Is there a better way to do this?

```
UPDATE tbl1 a,tbl2 b
SET a.q_id = b.q_id
WHERE   a.col IS NOT NULL
AND     a.col = b.col
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is equivalent to:

```
UPDATE tbl1 a JOIN
       tbl2 b
       ON a.col = b.col
    SET a.q_id = b.q_id;
```

The comparison to `NULL` is unnecessary.

However, that will not help performance.  An index on `tbl2(q_id, col)` should help performance considerably.

If you are updating lots of rows (says hundreds of thousands or more), you have to deal with logging issues.  In this case, breaking up the update into multiple steps might be a wise option.  Also, if there are multiple matches for each record in `tbl1`, then that might also slow down the query.

Comment: By 'breaking the update into multiple steps' do you mean running the update on a limited set of data?

Comment: @mucle6 . . . Essentially yes.  But that would only be for a very large number of updates.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tbl1 tb1 JOIN tbl2 tb2 ON tb1.col = tb2.col SET tb1.q_id = tb2.q_id;
```